# shared_ptr assignment: order of reference counting

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

When you use the copy assignment operator of a `shared_ptr`, conceptually, the `shared_ptr` on the left hand side of the assignment would need to decrement the reference count of the object it currently owns, and then increment the reference count of the object on the right-hand side of the assignment.  (Assuming, of course, that both pointers are non-null.)

So an implementation might look something like the following pseudo code:

```
shared_ptr& operator = (const shared_ptr& rhs)
{
   decrement_reference_count(this->m_ptr);
   this->m_ptr = rhs.m_ptr;
   increment_reference_count(this->m_ptr);
   return *this;
}
```

But note that here we decrement the reference count of `this` ***before*** we increment the reference count of `rhs`.  We could also do it the other way around.  My question is, does the standard actually specify the order here?

**Why it makes a difference**: it could make a *big* difference in the event that there is some kind of dependency between the reference count of `this` and the reference count of `lhs`.  For example, suppose both are part of a linked list structure, where the `next` pointer in each linked node is a `shared_ptr`.  So, decrementing the reference count of any node in the structure could trigger a destructor, which would then set off a chain reaction and decrement the reference count (and possibly also destruct) every other node in the chain.

So, supposing a situation where the reference count of `lhs` is affected by the reference count of `this`, it makes a big difference if we *first* decrement `this`, or we first increment `lhs`.  If we first increment `lhs` *before* decrementing `this`, then we can be sure that `lhs` will not end up being destructed when we decrement `this`.

But does the standard actually specify an order here?  As far as I can see, the only thing the standard says is that the copy assignment operator is equivalent to the expression:

```
shared_ptr(lhs).swap(*this)
```

But I can't really wrap my head around the implications (if any) that this equivalency might have in regard to the order of decrementing/incrementing the reference counts.

So does the standard specify an order here?  Or is this implementation defined behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The Standard says [20.7.2.2.3] that

```
shared_ptr& operator=(const shared_ptr& r) noexcept;
```

has effects equivalent to

```
shared_ptr(r).swap(*this)
```

This means constructing a temporary, which increments `r`'s reference count, then swapping its data with `*this`, then destroying the temporary, which means decrementing the reference count that used to belong to `*this`.

Answer (score 1):

It must increment the reference counter first, in case `rhs` is `this`. Otherwise it could inadvertently destroy the pointee when the reference counter is 1. It could check whether `this == &rhs` but this check is unnecessary if the reference counter increment is performed before the decrement.

`shared_ptr(lhs).swap(*this)` does not suffer from this issue because it creates a copy first, thus incrementing the reference counter first.